# Find the class name of a relation from the instance of a model in ember JS

Tags: ember.js

I have `foo` an instance of the ember-data model `thing`. thing.js has the following property :

`owner: DS.belongsTo('user')`

If I have `foo` with an empty owner, how can I, with only `foo` and the `'owner'` string, retrieve the value `'user'` representing the model of the owner relation?

EDIT: I want to allow my select-relation component to works with relations where the name is different from the class name

Comment: Hey @Syl, are there any more details you can share about what your current model relationships look like? Using a different attribute name for a relationship is a pretty normal thing to do. I think you might be missing some data in the store or your api responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I can do the following :

`this.get('model').get('_internalModel._relationships.initializedRelationships.'+this.get('relation')+'.relationshipMeta.type')`

`model` being an instance and `relation` the string of the relation name, it correctly return the model of the relation.

EDIT : a better solution not using private API courtesy from the ember discord :

```
function getRelatedModelName(record, relationName){
        let ParentModelClass = record.constructor;
        let meta  = get(ParentModelClass, 'relationshipsByName').get(relationName);
        return meta.type;
      }
```

Comment: This solution is not advisable because it appears to rely on private API. Underscores usually mean that. Like most semver projects, in Ember Data, private API can be changed at any time without following a deprecation process. This could break without warning.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have some work to do to finish setting up your relationships. Have a read through [this page](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/relationships/#toc_one-to-many) of the guides.

If the relationships are set up correctly, to get the associated user, you should be able to do `foo.owner`. This assumes that users are already present in the store. I recommend using the [Ember Inspector](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/ember-inspector/) browser plugin to debug the relationships.

Comment: I was making a genereic select component to choose a belong to relation. WIth only the record and the name of a relation, it does not work when the relation has a different name than the model ( `owner belongsTo('user')` ). When the select set up the relation after selecting a value, it must do a peekRecord, and it needs the model name.

Comment: Oh I see now what you mean about needing the model name. Thank you for explaining. I’m going to share this in Ember Discord chat and see if anyone else can add an answer here. I am pretty sure it can be done without private API.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a use case for [typeForRelationship](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.4/classes/DS.Model/methods/rollbackAttribute?anchor=typeForRelationship).

In your example you should be able to do something like

```
store.modelFor('thing').typeForRelationship('owner', store);
```

If you don't like that approach you can use the [belongsTo reference API](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.4/classes/DS.Model/methods/rollbackAttribute?anchor=belongsTo), where you use the meta data from the relationship to get the type

```
foo.belongsTo('owner').type
```

The only thing with that approach is that the `type` property may not be public API and possible (though unlikely) to change at some point.